# element.style not being overridden by custom css

Tags: css, wordpress, overriding

I am new to WordPress and am working on my first website. I am using a plugin for a livechat, which has a colour that is not to my liking. Seeing that the background colour for the button was set using inline CSS, I tried overriding the background colour using a child theme. However, for some reason it's not overriding the colour. I tried the below codes but none seemed to work.

```css
    #divClosedChatBar {
        background-color: #222;
    }

    #divClosedChatBar {
        background-color: #222 !important;
    }

    #divClosedChatBar[style] {
        background-color: #222 !important;
    }
```

```html
    <div id="divClosedChatBar" style="position:relative;width:205px;height:38px;top:0px;right:0px;bottom:0px;left:0px;overflow:hidden;border:0px;margin:0px;padding:0px;background-color:#1B68FF;text-align:center;cursor:pointer;vertical-align:middle;border-top-right-radius:5px;-webkit-border-top-right-radius:5px;-moz-border-top-right-radius:5px;border-top-left-radius:5px;-webkit-border-top-left-radius:5px;-moz-border-top-left-radius:5px;box-sizing:border-box;-webkit-box-sizing:border-box;-moz-box-sizing:border-box;-ms-box-sizing:border-box;">
        <div id="divUnreadMessages" style="float:left;position:absolute;height:16px;line-height:16px;margin-left:5px;margin-top:11.5px;padding: 0px;background-color:#FE6700;border-radius: 4px;">
            <span id="txtUnreadMessages" style="display:none;padding:0px 3px 1px 3px; color:white;font-weight:bold;background: -webkit-gradient(linear, left top, left bottom, from(#FE9504), to(#FE6700));background: -moz-linear-gradient(top,  #FE9504,  #FE6700);-webkit-border-radius: 4px;-moz-border-radius: 4px;border-radius: 4px;">0</span>
        </div>
        <span id="txtHelpChat" style="display:inline-block;cursor:pointer;margin-top:10.5px;margin-right:auto;margin-left:auto;font-size:15px;color:#FFFFFF;-webkit-touch-callout:none;-webkit-user-select:none;-khtml-user-select:none;-moz-user-select:none;-ms-user-select:none;user-select:none;">Leave us a message</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Can you add the inline style added and on which element/selector?

Comment: @MattiaAstorino Thanks for the reply. Edited the post with the full HTML element.

Comment: The second block should work as expected. Check the fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/ena81L5y/

Comment: @MattiaAstorino Thanks for the reply. I tried all three of them but none are working. I even tried changing the background colour of every div and everything changed except that div.. I think it has something to do with the plugin of WordPress.

Comment: @JohnnyLong agreed it should work. What can you see when you inspect the `<div>` in your browser? Are you sure there isn't another style sheet setting this color with `!important` and a CSS selector with more precedence than yours?

Comment: @julien.giband Thanks for the reply. Here is a screenshot of my code on the console. https://imgur.com/QoB5ZX6

Comment: @JohnnyLong unfortunately, the focus is not on `#divClosedChatbar` on your screenshot so I can't see if it has additional CSS